# Как я могу узнать выделен ли рядок для вставки или нет?

Tags: c#

Есть элемент listView1. В него я добавляю элементы. После чего мне нужно выделить рядок и вставить в него элемент.

Добавления и вставка происходит после нажатия на кнопки, а значения берутся с полей, но когда я не выделяю рядок таблицы listView происходит ошибка. Как я могу узнать выделен ли рядок для вставки или нет.

```
private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int ind = listView1.FocusedItem.Index; //индекс куда вставить
     string [] values = {textBox1};
     ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(values);
     listView1.Items.Insert(index, it);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Больше экспериментируйте самостоятельно!

Посмотрите, чему равен `listView1.FocusedItem.Index` и `.SelectedIndex`, когда никакой элемент списка не виден.

Comment: спасибо. нужно было проверить listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && listView1.FocusedItem.Index >= 0